# How to print word document using PrintDocument class

Tags: c#, printing, ms-word, printdocument

My requirement is to print a Word document using c#.

Since Interop Word is not recommended to use at server side, I would like to print Word file using `PrintDocument` class.

So, how to print Word document using c#?

I tried the below code, but it printed out 2 blank pages:

```
 PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();
            printDoc.DocumentName = "E:\\WordPrint\\Output\\TEST.docx";
            printDoc.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "Bullzip PDF Printer";
            printDoc.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterSettings.Copies = 2;
            printDoc.Print();
```

Comment: Could you leave your code to see where is your issue, or what did you try to print your document?.

Comment: You don't.  Printing a word document would require using Word.

Comment: @JesseR.Jose
PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();
            printDoc.DocumentName = "E:\\WordPrint\\Output\\TEST.docx";
            printDoc.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "Bullzip PDF Printer";
            printDoc.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterSettings.Copies = 2;
            printDoc.Print();

Comment: @LarsTech, There are few SDK's like Spire Doc .NET available, which allows to print word doc without using word.
How that is possible?

Comment: @sivaprakash edit your question an left your code there.

Comment: They aren't using PrintDocument.  You have to go shopping for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
try 
{ 
    streamToPrint = new StreamReader ("C:\\My Documents\\MyFile.txt"); 

    try 
    { 
        printFont = new Font("Arial", 10); 
        PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument(); 
        pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler (this.pd_PrintPage); 
        pd.Print(); 
    } 
    finally 
    {
        streamToPrint.Close(); 
    } 
} 
catch (Exception ex) 
{ 
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); 
}
```

You can find more information on the msdn site:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument(v=vs.110).aspx